# How can I share my website in progress to partner?

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, hosting

I'm developing a website in python (with django and GIT) for an association, and I am to a point where I need to share my work for approval from the team.

I have around 50 people who need to be able to access my "website" 24/7.

Apparently, free hosting is not the best way to do it (see answers to my original question).

I've never done such a thing, so I'm a bit lost. It looks like I can use without too many investment in effort my ubuntu computer. And apparently there is other tools for this application.

I'm looking for advise and explanation on how to implement a working solution.

EDIT: The 50 people are not in my local network.

[ORIGINAL POST BELOW]

What is the best way to share my website to partners?

I'm developing a website for an association, and I want to know if there is a way to let them access to my work in progress.

I was thinking of free hosting solutions?

I'm not looking for a professional host, I'm just looking for a way to share my work with maximum 50 peoples.

Is there another solution?

I have an ubuntu pc that I could use as server (I have high speed connection).

(I don't know if this is relevant, but I'm using python-django and bootstrap for the design)

Comment: I tend to use heroku.

Comment: Python has `http.server` in the standard library, which could be useful, and is probably easier than any other solution.

Comment: Get a droplet on digital ocean.  It's $5/month and basically required for web developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that these 50 users aren't on your local network. There are a few solutions:

- Like @njzk2 mentioned, [Heroku w/ Django](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django). This is an "app-centric" deployment web service.
- Amazon EC2 or other AWS options - Unless your app is for very resource heavy, this is a free/inexpensive option. Lots of information to google about this.
- [Python Anywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/DjangoTutorial) has "beginner" accounts that should be more than enough to meet your needs and allows for Django apps.

If these 50 people are all in your network and you really want to deploy, then you can hopefully spin up a VM somewhere and deploy through [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) or some other WSGI application server. There are many, many options for this.

Comment: The 50 users are not on my private network (I've added this info to my question, thx). I will look through Heroku with Django and accept your answer if it works for me ! Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Well, then use your ubuntu system, forward the right ports in your router and give your customers a link to your IPadres. I assume you use your ubuntu system as an webserver already for testing your site?

Comment: I'm developing on 2 different computers, a ubuntu VM at my office and a ubuntu computer at my home. For testing my website, I only use the django tool "python manage.py runserver x.x.x.x:yyyy". Can you redirect me to a good tuto for beginner on how to use my ubuntu computer as server ?